# string format with JOIN inside SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression, ssrs-2016

I am using an SSRS expression to format the result of a string like this based on a condition

```
  = IIf(my_condition,"All active items",JOIN (Parameters!SelectedBooks.label,"<br/>"))
```

This will make the resultant string comes on next lines automatically if my condition is false and is working fine . Instead of

```
 <br/>
```

i would like to use li tags

```
 <li>Parameters!SelectedBooks.label</li>
```

If li is used my items will comes better in HTML view. So how can i use a string format or use 3 sections with JOIN of SSRS expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this expression should get you what you need.

```
="<li>" & Join(Parameters!SelectedBooks.Label, "</li><li>") & "</li>"
```

No need to get too crazy with Format and Join, I think simple string concatenation and Join should do the trick.

Result in preview mode:

[image: Preview Image]

This will display the raw HTML used in a TextBox and in preview mode, so I don't know what the value is. That part I leave up to you.

Hope this helps.